# Folders with custom columns in Pages library

Tags: sharepoint-online, content-type, pages

I'd like to create a custom navigation for my site's Pages library. To do this, I'm going to organize the pages in folders, and have a few extra columns on the folders, such as a CSS class, display order, subheading, etc. I've created a new site content type, inheriting from the Folder content type. I've added the extra columns to the new folder content type, and I've added the content type to the Pages library. But when I try to create a new folder using this content type, I get a "Sorry, something went wrong" error.

Is it not possible to use custom folder content types in the Pages library? It works in a standard document library.

Comment: It should be possible. I tried it and it works on onprem farm. I don't see a reason why it shouldn't work in SharePoint Online. Try removing column by column from content type to see whether a certain column is causing the error.

Comment: I don't think it's the columns causing the error. I tried adding another folder content type with no extra columns - same problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally found a solution to this. The error occurred only when logged in as a site collection administrator. When logged in as a normal user, it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Try to enable below option.

I did test in my online environment, I could create folder with custom folder content type(one custom number field), if issue exists, try to remove fields for your content type to confirm this caused by complex filed type.

[image]

Comment: That option is already enabled, and adding a standard folder works. Using a new folder content type with no extra columns also fails.

Comment: You may submit a service request so online support engineer could check detailed error/information based on Correlation id.